# Forcing cost planner to start from a specific index seek

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My cypher query

```
EXPLAIN MATCH (b:Block)<-[:INCLUDED_IN]-(tx:Transaction {pstype: 0})
WHERE 1540512000 <= b.time < 1540598400
RETURN count(tx);
```

produces the following execution plan

```
--------------------------------------------+
| Operator          | Estimated Rows | Identifiers     | Other                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 |
+-------------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +ProduceResults   |             12 | count(tx)       |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       |
| |                 +----------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +EagerAggregation |             12 | count(tx)       |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       |
| |                 +----------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +Filter           |            136 | anon[16], b, tx | AndedPropertyInequalities(Variable(b),Property(Variable(b),PropertyKeyName(time)),GreaterThanOrEqual(Property(Variable(b),PropertyKeyName(time)),Parameter(  AUTOINT2,Integer)), LessThan(Property(Variable(b),PropertyKeyName(time)),Parameter(  AUTOINT1,Integer))) |
| |                 +----------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +Expand(All)      |           9052 | anon[16], b, tx | (tx)-[anon[16]:INCLUDED_IN]->(b)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
| |                 +----------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +NodeIndexSeek    |           9052 | tx              | :Transaction(pstype)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  |
+-------------------+----------------+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

which executes way too slow because the first NodeIndexSeekByRange returns tens of millions of nodes instead of 9052. Using NodeIndexSeekByRange on b:Block(time) would produce around 600 nodes.

I have tried forcing the execution plan to start from b:Block(time), but instead it still keeps using NodeIndexSeek on tx:Transaction(pstype):

```
EXPLAIN MATCH (b:Block)<-[:INCLUDED_IN]-(tx:Transaction {pstype: 0})
USING INDEX b:Block(time)
WHERE 1540512000 <= b.time < 1540598400
RETURN count(tx);
```

produces

```
+-------------------------+----------------+-----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| Operator                | Estimated Rows | Identifiers     | Other                                                        |
+-------------------------+----------------+-----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| +ProduceResults         |             12 | count(tx)       |                                                              |
| |                       +----------------+-----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| +EagerAggregation       |             12 | count(tx)       |                                                              |
| |                       +----------------+-----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| +NodeHashJoin           |            136 | anon[16], b, tx | b                                                            |
| |\                      +----------------+-----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| | +NodeIndexSeekByRange |          14703 | b               | :Block(time) >= {  AUTOINT2} AND :Block(time) < {  AUTOINT1} |
| |                       +----------------+-----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| +Expand(All)            |           9052 | anon[16], b, tx | (tx)-[anon[16]:INCLUDED_IN]->(b)                             |
| |                       +----------------+-----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| +NodeIndexSeek          |           9052 | tx              | :Transaction(pstype)                                         |
+-------------------------+----------------+-----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The only way I have gotten it to work fast is by using the rule planner: (multiple orders of magnitude faster)

```
CYPHER planner=rule MATCH (b:Block)
WHERE 1540512000 <= b.time < 1540598400
WITH b
MATCH (b)<-[:INCLUDED_IN]-(tx:Transaction {pstype: 0})
RETURN count(tx);
```

**Is there a way to make it work when using the cost planner?**

Both :Block(time) and :Transaction(pstype) are indexed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using a [join hint](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/query-tuning/using/#_hinting_a_join_on_a_single_node) on `tx` along with your index hint, which should ensure you only expand from one direction:

```
EXPLAIN 
MATCH (b:Block)<-[:INCLUDED_IN]-(tx:Transaction {pstype: 0})
USING INDEX b:Block(time)
USING JOIN ON tx
WHERE 1540512000 <= b.time < 1540598400
RETURN count(tx);
```

Alternately you could restructure your query a bit so the `tx` node isn't initially part of the pattern, but enforced in the WHERE clause. You'll need to split the MATCH in 2, but I don't think you'll need any planner hints:

```
EXPLAIN 
MATCH (tx:Transaction {pstype: 0})
MATCH (b:Block)<-[:INCLUDED_IN]-(x)
WHERE 1540512000 <= b.time < 1540598400
AND x = tx
RETURN count(tx);
```

EDIT

Okay, let's try another approach then:

```
EXPLAIN 
MATCH (b:Block)<-[:INCLUDED_IN]-(x)
WHERE 1540512000 <= b.time < 1540598400
AND x.pstype = 0 // AND 'Transaction' in labels(x)
RETURN count(tx);
```

If we leave off the label then it can't use an indexed lookup. If there are other nodes besides :Transaction nodes that have a `pstype` property, you could try uncommenting the line where we use an alternate way to see if the node has that label (I don't think this will use an index lookup, but not completely sure).

Another alternative (unsure if this will work) is to use pattern comprehension to get a list of results from a pattern (after the initial match is found to `b`) and summing the sizes of the results:

```
EXPLAIN 
MATCH (b:Block)
WHERE 1540512000 <= b.time < 1540598400
RETURN sum(size([(b)<-[:INCLUDED_IN]-(x:Transaction) WHERE x.pstype = 0 | x])) as count
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Unfortunately neither of the solutions worked. 

The latter query produced exactly same query plan as my attempt using the JOIN hint. The first query produced otherwise the same result but NodeHashJoin was replaced by ValueHashJoin.

Comment: Added a few alternatives to try

Comment: I can't test your solution right now but I'm pretty sure that leaving off the label will work so I marked your solution as accepted.